# Flash[:notice] remains after form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When the form gets submitted the flash message is displayed  and the user remains at the same page with all fields filled.Now if one of the required fields id deleted and again we submit the form, the error is not displayed and the flash[:notice] is displayed.When i refresh the page the notice goes off.unable to figure out the reason .i have given the view code and in controller

```
flash[:notice] = "Saved Successfully"
```

View code:

```
   <b><h3><%= flash[:notice] %></h3></b>
<% semantic_form_for(@featured_business, {:url => "#{@signin_link}".gsub(/\/+/, '/'), :html => {:multipart => true, :class => 'validate business'}}) do |f| %>
<% f.inputs do %>

  <%= hidden_field_tag 'more_validations_required' %>
  <%= f.input :name, :label => ' Name:' , :input_html => { :style => "width:240px;" }%>
  <%= f.input :contact_name, :label => 'Contact name:',:required => false, :input_html => { :style => "width:240px;" } %>
  <%= f.input :phone, :label => 'Phone Number:', :input_html => { :style => "width:240px;" }  %>
  <%= f.input :email, :label => 'Email:', :input_html => { :class => 'email' } , :input_html => { :style => "width:240px;" } %>


  <%= f.commit_button :label => "", :button_html => {:class => 'signup business'} %>
<% end %>
```

<% end %>

Comment: Follow what link by @Gazler, or a hacky solution can be `<%= flash.delete(:notice) %>`

Answer (score 1):

Flash messages exist for the next page only.  If you refresh the page then the flash message is no longer stored in the session.

Here is a good blog post to help you understand flash messages.  http://travisonrails.com/2008/08/17/working-with-the-flash-hash

Comment: ..thanx .i'll surely hav a look